# How can I get my margin notes to indent themselves into the text, shifting the text over?

Tags: margins, indentation, marginpar, marginnote

I'm looking for my outer margin notes to be pushed into the text, and the text to flow around them, like the picture below:
[image]

I'm using scrbook, and I still want to margin notes to have the same alignment as they normally do (left aligned on odd pages, and vice versa for evens).

I would like the margin notes and the regular text to have the same margins essentially, but the pushed text to obviously have larger margins.

I have a large document with many margin notes, so I can't go and manually make some sort of command like `\marginnoteindent{note}{paragraphToIndent}` to just force the paragraph I pick as #2 to shift over, I need it to work via e.g. `\marginnoteindent{note}`, if that sort of thing is possible.

Comment: Margin notes are for the margin.  This looks for like a case for [wrapfig](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Wrapping_text_around_figures). The "figure" doesn't need to be an `\includegraphics`; you can put what you want in the box.

Comment: Not sure, but putting two wrapfigs into one paragraph might be difficult, since it is based on \parshape.

Comment: I remember seeing some plain-text answer to this...

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm, that worked quite well and was very close to what I am looking for. But JohnKormylo is right, two of my wrapfig margin notes in one paragraph does make the second note float away from where it should be, which is a bit annoying, because it does look very good otherwise. I may be able to restructure those problem paragraphs if there is no perfect solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires manually placing the notes at the ends of lines.  It requires you to first print the paragraph without notes, then figure out precisely where you want the notes to go (one at a time in sequence).

You can insert the note in the middle of a hyphenated word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% fake text

\newlength{\insertwidth}
\setlength{\insertwidth}{1.5cm}
\newcommand{\insertcount}{}% reserve global names
\newsavebox{\insertbox}

\newcommand{\insertnote}[1]% #1 = text to insert
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{\footnotesize\parbox[t]{\insertwidth}{\raggedright #1}}% measure height
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0+1.2\baselineskip\relax
  \count1=\numexpr \dimen0/\baselineskip\relax% round down
  \dimen1=\baselineskip
  \multiply\dimen1 by \count1
  \dimen2=\dimexpr \dimen1-\ht0-\dp0\relax% extra top and bottom margin
  \xdef\insertcount{-\the\count1}%
  \global\setbox\insertbox=\hbox{\raisebox{\dimexpr \dp\strutbox-0.5\dimen2}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox0}\hskip\columnsep}%
\egroup
{\parskip=0pt\parfillskip=0pt\par}%
\hangafter=\insertcount
\hangindent=\dimexpr \insertwidth+\columnsep\relax
\noindent\llap{\usebox\insertbox}%
\ignorespaces}
  

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
\insertnote{Resistance of the government}
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa
ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas
lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum.
Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna.  Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tin-\insertnote{Riots}
cidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim.
Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cursus
pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum
pellentesque felis eu massa.


\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, works exactly as I imagined, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer for Latex [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680582/section-title-inside-the-indentation-of-a-par-in-plain-tex):

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\def\hangpad{.25cm}
\newcount\hangcount
\def\inindent#1{%
    \hangcount=0\relax%
    \setbox0=\vbox to 0pt{%
        \tabskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax%
        \everycr={\noalign{\global\advance\hangcount by -1\relax}}%
        \halign{\hfil\bf##\hfil\crcr%
            #1\crcr
        }%
        \vss%
    }%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr\wd0 + \hangpad * 2\relax%
    \hangafter=\hangcount%
    \noindent\kern-\hangindent\hbox{\kern\hangpad\relax\box0\kern\hangpad\relax}%
}

\inindent{La premiére partie\cr (chap.~1--29)}%
Après avoir donné une brève définition du monde (1,1), Ampélius utilise le rappel de la
théorie des quatre éléments (1,2) comme schéma directeur de l'exposé d'astronomie et de
géographie qui forme la première section de cette première partie\thinspace:
Après avoir donné une brève définition du monde (1,1), Ampélius utilise le rappel de la
théorie des quatre éléments (1,2) comme schéma directeur de l'exposé d'astronomie et de
géographie qui forme la première section de cette première partie\thinspace:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @user574859 , very interesting answer, although it seems like in this method margin notes can only be placed at the very start of a paragraph, and if they are placed mid paragraph, the text shows up mid paragraph while the gap for the text is at the start of the paragraph

Comment: Then you can either adapt the second answer cited above (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680582/section-title-inside-the-indentation-of-a-par-in-plain-tex) or check out the `picinpar` package.